# Batch Image processor that adds white space

Tags: image, photoshop, batch-processing, fireworks

I'm looking for a way to ADD in white space to images so that they fit an exact dimension. I have product images of all shapes and sizes and I need every image to be exactly 100px x 200px.

This is not for our site, but rather for a vendor's site. Their requirements.

So, I can batch them to fit within that container, but I haven't found software to add in whitespace.

e.g.

- Image1 = 100 x 80
- Image2 = 80 x 200

For image 1, I want to add 120px of blank space to the bottom.
For image 2, I want to add 10px of space to the left and right.

What tool can I use to automate this for 400 products?

Comment: you tell us: what have you found so far while looking on the internet, and what did they do wrong that you could not use them?

Comment: on a side note, realise that you're just asking how to batch create compound images of "a fixed 100x200px solid color" and your own image on top of that. Don't make things harder than they need to be.

Comment: ImageMagick is a command line set of graphic manipulation tools.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick can be used for this task:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border

If multiple images are concerned, `mogrify` is the command (same flags as `convert` in the example, yet `mogrify` accepts multiple images as its input).